# docker folder takes too much space

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2

I have an aws ec2 instance running docker. The problem is `/var/lib/docker` directory size keeps increasing.

Under it, these two subdirectories take most space:

```
8.4G    ./overlay2
43G     ./volumes
```

The running application shouldn't take that much space. So I digged into `./volumes` the disk usage there is like:

```
0   ./01f77dcc583d434c55435ca2d255a4db5caabd4312bc23439562b8c3cc0335e5
301M    ./36cb5b2025508bcbbdd12d222c2a61961f890e01d66c63fa8c54fcf8af6ee845
0   ./cf5a236c8355b5776a340a90cd1d0c1498a4c23f886d093567e08b2c81d54c29
0   ./5a01732daed19e4c46c50bba8329d3760b9421ac182e16f88f9f840d9d21073a
301M    ./60a8318f278b2943121e2540e67e74928fa31b089ea4ba1a11066f00a458a883
0   ./b44be033795633706217140dd50d73f43cf01be6703e4eea194e0548dd13f2ea
301M    ./c577cd0e8d004d85a5288fe0b597e7c463051a76e59bea63844b68161775b5a9
...
```

Lines like that repeat a lot, seems like dangling containers. I then tried `docker system prune -f -a`, only claimed me less than 1G.

What's going wrong there, and what's a good solution? Thanks!

**UPDATE**

`docker volume prune` claimed 44G space to me. So is it when docker removes a stopped container, it doesn't remove the volume as well? How can I prevent it from happening again?

Comment: `docker system prune --volumes` will prune dangling volumes. BE CAREFUL AND REVIEW those volumes beforehand!!!!

Comment: The answer depends on how you start and stop your containers.

Comment: @jannis Thanks! Just found from doc, "If you are on Docker 17.06.1 or higher and want to also prune volumes, add the --volumes flag".  https://docs.docker.com/config/pruning/#prune-everything

Comment: What's the image you're running?  Does the Dockerfile have a `VOLUME` directive that's causing Docker to create anonymous volumes?  Since volumes are designed to hold user data `docker rm` or `docker system prune` won't delete them by default.

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes, there is. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 1):

First, run the command

```
docker system df
```

to check your Docker system's disk usage. Next, verify if you have any build-cache that might be consuming your space. If it is, you can free up space by executing the following command:

```
docker builder prune
```

That works for me hope you solve this

Answer (score 0):

Usually to prevent this, a cronjob can be set, that runs periodically the command `docker system prune`. You can check for details [here](https://rzymek.github.io/post/docker-prune)

This need to be used carefully, since the prune command can have unwanted results. For details please read the comment below.

Comment: A cron job doing `docker system prune` is a very very bad idea.

Comment: It would be better if you elaborate rather than just say it is not good. It generates much more value to the topic.

Comment: `docker system prune`, as every 'delete' (especially bulk delete as in this case) operation, is risky and may have unforeseen consequences. This is why it requires user consent to proceed. Automating it and thus removing the need for the consent (with `--force` option) may cause harm to less aware Docker users. OFC it might come in handy at times but should be used with extreme caution. For the sake of those less experienced engineers it should be mentioned that a rule of thumb is to think twice each time you use a command with the `--force` parameter.

Comment: Yes, indeed I agree that it can be used carefully, but it does not disqualify the use case, add long as you know what you are doing. I edited my answer, just in case.